# Twitter V2 Api filtered Stream Endpoint

Tags: twitter, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-api-v2

I have elevated access to twitter api v2 and I’m using filtered stream endpoint for realtime events. Now after some random duration, I stop getting response from the stream.

It does give me the `datakeepalive` signals but doesn’t trigger according to rules. It works fine again if I restart my server. My server is deployed on ec2.

As per [Twitter v1 stream endpoint documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/connecting), `A client stops reading data suddenly. If the rate of Tweets being read off of the stream drops suddenly, the connection will be closed.` I'm confused if this applies to v2 endpoint too.

Any guidance or more info on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: facing the same issue, looking forward to any helpful answers.